# how to put php code in a wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created custom page in wordpress and in the page I have a form where users can upload a banner, and input some text.

The code is working perfectly on a local server. The problem is when I transfer to the live page, it is displayed as text instead of working normally.

I have tried to search for the page in cPanel but have later realized the pages are not stored as normal pages but stored in a database.

Please help me how to make my form work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a php code (this is a code not a content) as a post content from the admin panel. A php file must be created (or using the functions.php) to serve that page and put the code there.

Find and open the functions.php file. It is located under the `wp-content/themes/yourthemename/` folder.
At the end of the file (but before the `?>` symbols if exist) add this code

```
function custom_function_for_your_page() {
    // put your php code here
}
add_shortcode( 'custom_functionality', 'custom_function_for_your_page' );
```

Now as you guess, you can put the php code right below this line `// put your php code here`.
This is a shortcode. Now you can put that shortcode into the page content.
Open that page from the admin panel, where you've tried to put the php code. Instead of that code put this `[custom_functionality]`.

Good luck :) Tell me if it doesn't work, we'll try more.

Comment: I don't know how I can contact you privately :)
I'll try to explain in the answer.

Comment: got it, you ca delete it

Comment: if we can put this code in index.php , it will be on all pages. is it correct?

Comment: @NeiL , yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may need a plugin, here is one such plugin I know about:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/

Comment: Thanks, One problem though, the plugin warned me that it has not been tested with my version of wordpress, and that's right, it did not work. I'm running Version 4.2.2